# How to get node ID from drupal 7 when i know title (title shouldnt be duplicated) Drupal

Tags: nodes, entities

My module is creating node with title "123title", after this i want to create next node, with entity reference field whose have to contain id of node with title "123tile" whose i created before. –

Comment: Hello. I thought I can answer you, when I read question's title. But then I read question's body and I realized I have no idea what exactly are you trying to do. Could you please try to rewrite it in more friendly form? Please remember: you know what you mean. We know only what you wrote.

Comment: My module is creating node with title "123title", after this i want to create next node, with entity reference field whose have to contain id of node with title "123tile" whose i created before.

Comment: Please remember you can [edit your question](http://drupal.stackexchange.com/posts/124466/edit) to provide clarifications etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As suggested by Mołot you can do this with EntityFieldQuery.

```
// Initialize EntityFieldQuery.
$query = new EntityFieldQuery();
$query->entityCondition('entity_type', 'node');  

$query->propertyCondition('title', "My title", "=");


// Execute query and collect results
$result = $query->execute();  

$nids = array();
if (isset($result['node'])) {
  $nids = array_keys($result['node']);
}
```

In the example $nids will be an array with all node ids that have the title "My title". Entity field query really helps you when the query gets more complicated. You don't have to do joins for example yourself but can instead do something like `$query->fieldCondition('field_news_types', 'value', 'spotlight', '=')` which using db_select would require joins on tables.

Comment: +1 Note that _by default_ this method will apply [node access rights](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!node!node.module/group/node_access/7) whereas the `db_select()` method won't.

Answer (score 1):

```
$title='put title here';
$node_id = db_select('node', 'n')
  ->fields('n',array('nid'))
  ->condition('title',$title,'=')
  ->execute()
  ->fetchField();
```

Now $node_id contains node id that you want.

Comment: Too bad that "official method" [EntityFieldQuery](https://www.drupal.org/node/1343708) can't work, as title is not a field. Probably what you wrote is, indeed, the only way to get it fast. **To the OP** remember that if title is not exact, `$node_id` will not contain a valid node id. Put some checks in place if you will use this piece of code.

Comment: @Mołot you can though do it with EntityFieldQuery by $query->propertyCondition('title',  "My title", "=");

Comment: @PontusNilsson where is my mind... Forgot about that, working with `fieldCondition` only for quite some time. If you'll post an answer using it, I'll gladly upvote.

Comment: yes we can also do it using EntityFieldQuery as @pontus nilsson said.